# How to keep Netbeans from automatically copying configuration files to private folder?

Tags: netbeans, configuration-files

In Netbeans it is possible to create specific run configurations (main class, parameters) through the "Project Properties"->"Run" settings.

Such configuration files are then stored in the nbproject/configs folder.

Now, whenever I open and save the project properties, this configuration is "copied" to nbproject/private/configs.

Can I keep Netbeans from creating these private configuration files?

The problem is that the files are not copied exactly. If my original config looks like:

```
main.class=[myPackage].MyMain

arg1=SomeValue
arg2=SomeOtherValue

application.args=${arg1} ${arg2}
```

Then the "copied" file only contains the single line

```
application.args=${arg1} ${arg2}
```

which obviously cannot not work, since my main class then gets those strings literally.

Comment: I have the same problem.