# Where are Java run configuration arguments stored in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a NetBeans project stored in Git. If I change the runtime arguments...

[image]

it doesn't show up as a change in Git. So where are these stored?

Comment: Could you post your `.gitignore`? Would be useful to know what build system you are using to - Ant or Maven.

Comment: build system: whatever the builtin method is (Ant I guess).

Comment: Oh -- I think I figured it out. Sometimes netbeans puts configs in nbproject/configs, other times in nbproject/private/configs (which is in my .gitignore). Odd.

Comment: seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405010/how-to-keep-netbeans-from-automatically-copying-configuration-files-to-private-f

Comment: This is a great question, not sure why anyone downvoted it. NetBeans' insistence on storing things like this in user-specific locations instead of project-specific locations really makes it hard to collaborate on a project from more than one computer, let alone with a large team.

Answer (score 0):

unrelated to Git, but for others looking for where arguments are stored... I found that for a simple application, the arguments were stored in the private properties file
  ...SimpleJavaApplicationTest\nbproject\private\private.properties

Cheers,